# session_set_save_handler and write on php 5.4.12

Tags: php, session, session-set-save-handler

I am using `session_set_save_handler()` to save sessions to a DB. 
 
After moving from php v.5.3 to v.5.4  the `write()` function is not called at all; neither when calling the `session_write_close()` function, nor when the script is terminated (it was working correctly before and there were no changes done to code). The `read()`, `open()` and `close()` functions are still called as usual. 
I know there are several changes in php 5.4 related to `session_set_save_handler()` mechanism. Does anybody have similar problem or know what was changed?

```
class session {

    private $table_name;

    function __construct() {
        $this->table_name = SESS_TABLE;

        session_set_save_handler(array($this, 'open'), array($this, 'close'), array($this, 'read'), array($this, 'write'), array($this, 'destroy'), array($this, 'gc'));
        register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');

    }

    function start_session($session_name, $secure) {
        global $session;

        // Make sure the session cookie is not accessable via javascript.
        $httponly = true;

        // Hash algorithm to use for the sessionid. (use hash_algos() to get a list of available hashes.)
        $session_hash = 'sha512';

        // Check if hash is available
        if (in_array($session_hash, hash_algos())) {
          // Set the has function.
          ini_set('session.hash_function', $session_hash);
        }
        // How many bits per character of the hash.
        // The possible values are '4' (0-9, a-f), '5' (0-9, a-v), and '6' (0-9, a-z, A-Z, "-", ",").
        ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 5);

        // Force the session to only use cookies, not URL variables.
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);

        // Get session cookie parameters 
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); 
        // Set the parameters
        session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
        // Change the session name 
        session_name($session_name);
        // Now we cat start the session
        session_start();
        // This line regenerates the session and delete the old one. 
        // It also generates a new encryption key in the database. 
        if(USE_REGENERATE){
            $this->regenerate_id();
        }
        //session_regenerate_id(true);    
    }

    function regenerate_id() {

        $old_sess_id = session_id();
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        $new_sess_id = session_id();
        Logger::write($old_sess_id .'-'.$new_sess_id   ,  'session.log');

        $time = time();
        if(!isset($this->u_stmt)) {
          $this->u_stmt = $this->db->prepare(" UPDATE ".$this->table_name." set id = ? where id=?");
        }

        $this->u_stmt->bind_param('ss', $new_sess_id,$old_sess_id);
        $this->u_stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }

    function open() {
        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = SESS_USER;
        $pass = SESS_PASSWORD;
        $name = SESS_DBNAME;
        $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);
        $this->db = $mysqli;
        return true;
    }

    function close() {
        $this->db->close();
        return true;
    }

    function read($id) {
        global $s_read_start, $s_read_end;
        $s_read_start = microtime(true);
        if(!isset($this->read_stmt)) {
          $this->read_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT data FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
        }
        $this->read_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $this->read_stmt->execute();
        $this->read_stmt->store_result();
        $this->read_stmt->bind_result($data);
        $this->read_stmt->fetch();
        $key = $this->getkey($id);
        $data = $this->decrypt($data, $key);
        $s_read_end = microtime(true);
        if($s_read_end-$s_read_start > MORE_THEN)
            error_log (date("Y-m-d H:i:s").' '.'READ: '. ($s_read_end-$s_read_start).PHP_EOL,3,BASE_DIR.'/logs/cookies.log');
        return $data;
    }

    function write($id, $data) {
        error_log (date("Y-m-d H:i:s").' '.'WRITE: '.PHP_EOL,3,BASE_DIR.'/logs/cookies.log');
        global $s_write_start, $s_write_end;
        $s_write_start = microtime(true);
        // Get unique key
        $key = $this->getkey($id);
        // Encrypt the data
        $data = $this->encrypt($data, $key);

        $time = time();
        if(!isset($this->w_stmt)) {
          $this->w_stmt = $this->db->prepare("REPLACE INTO ".$this->table_name." (id, set_time, data, session_key) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        }

        $this->w_stmt->bind_param('siss', $id, $time, $data, $key);
        $this->w_stmt->execute();
        $s_write_end = microtime(true);
        if($s_write_end-$s_write_start > MORE_THEN)
            error_log (date("Y-m-d H:i:s").' '.'WRITE: '. ($s_write_end-$s_write_start).PHP_EOL,3,BASE_DIR.'/logs/cookies.log');
        return true;
    }

    function destroy($id) {
        global $s_destroy_start, $s_destroy_end;
        $s_destroy_start = microtime(true);

        if(!isset($this->delete_stmt)) {
          $this->delete_stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE id = ?");
        }
        $this->delete_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $this->delete_stmt->execute();
        $s_destroy_end = microtime(true);
        if($s_destroy_end-$s_destroy_start > MORE_THEN)
            error_log (date("Y-m-d H:i:s").' '.'DESTROY: '. ($s_destroy_end-$s_destroy_start).PHP_EOL,3,BASE_DIR.'/logs/cookies.log');
        return true;
    }

    function gc($max) {
        global $s_gc_start, $s_gc_end;
        $s_gc_start = microtime(true);

        if(!isset($this->gc_stmt)) {
            $this->gc_stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE set_time < ?");
        }
        $old = time() - $max;
        $this->gc_stmt->bind_param('s', $old);
        $this->gc_stmt->execute();
        $s_gc_end = microtime(true);
        if($s_gc_end-$s_gc_start > MORE_THEN)
            error_log (date("Y-m-d H:i:s").' '.'GC: '. ($s_gc_end-$s_gc_start).PHP_EOL,3,BASE_DIR.'/logs/cookies.log');
        return true;
    }

    private function getkey($id) {
        if(!isset($this->key_stmt)) {
          $this->key_stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT session_key FROM ".$this->table_name." WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");
        }
        $this->key_stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $this->key_stmt->execute();
        $this->key_stmt->store_result();
        if($this->key_stmt->num_rows == 1) { 
          $this->key_stmt->bind_result($key);
          $this->key_stmt->fetch();
          return $key;
        } else {
          $random_key = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));
          return $random_key;
        }
    }

    private function encrypt($data, $key) {
        $salt = 'cH!swe!retReGu7W6bEDRup7usuDUh9THeD2CHeGE*ewr4n39=E@rAsp7c-Ph@pH';
        $key = substr(hash('sha256', $salt.$key.$salt), 0, 32);
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
        return $encrypted;
    }

    private function decrypt($data, $key) {
        $salt = 'cH!swe!retReGu7W6bEDRup7usuDUh9THeD2CHeGE*ewr4n39=E@rAsp7c-Ph@pH';
        $key = substr(hash('sha256', $salt.$key.$salt), 0, 32);
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return $decrypted;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$session = new session();
$session->start_session('name', false);
```

Sorry for some debug in the code.

Comment: Can you show the code? (if it is too much then post it to pastebin and share the link may also be ok)

Comment: seems like session_register_shutdown ( void ) is used in a way not intended for >= 5.4?  Use instead  `register_shutdown_function('shutdown');`?  Also, isn't there an interface you can use now too?

Comment: @ficuscr I can see no problem with `register_shutdown_function()`

Comment: I tried this change : register_shutdown_function('shutdown');  - it didn't help.   Due to debug I can see that close() function is called but it should be  called after write()!

Comment: Bah, think I confused myself there.  Anyway, My suggestion is if you are taking this to PHP >= 5.4 you might as well refactor a bit and make use of the [`SessionHandlerInterface`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php).  I fell like there is a mismatch of old and new approaches in your code.

Comment: Can you try this : http://pastebin.com/MzayDP6A

Comment: I have tried it. The object still exists.

Comment: Are you sure, that *session read* works?

Comment: the read() is called  but it can read nothing because nothing was written.  open() close() and read() are called.

Comment: That's why it is strange for me.

Comment: How do you make sure that *it is called* ?

Comment: I just added the dbug write to file there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26970/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-valery-patskevich)

Comment: I have tested with php 5.4.4-14 It works, meaning that write will being called

Comment: I have made tests  using SessionHandlerInterface (new in v.5.4). The open() read() and close() are called. write() is not called. And it do work on other servers. It seems to be some php build issue.  I have sent the question to shared hosting support about the php build. Thank you .

Comment: There's too much stuff in this code. You should boil this down to the shortest script that tests the functionality. Open session, write var. In your custom close, echo something.

Comment: Thanks for `$salt` `n pepper!

Comment: Maybe this will help you - Once when I was struggling with my own custom session handlers I noticed that if OOP was used - open/close/read/write were implemented as class methods - I was not able to make this work. Without OOP worked perfectly. Try using functions without classes - maybe you are struggling with the same stuff right now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your session object destroyed by PHP internal garbage collector before the shutdown function call. In this case you need to move `session_write_close()` function into destructor:

```
function __destruct() {
  session_write_close();
}
```

I recommend you to rewrite your code according to new session handling mechanism. Implement `SessionHandlerInterface` to aviod such behaviour in future.